# CSS3 fade animation should work but it doesn't

Tags: html, css

I spent half of the day making research for this problem but there doesn't seem to be solution. I am trying to make "fade" animation on pictures which are changed inside of the `slideshow-container`. I created `fade` as a photo container. Here is the HTML code:

The `changePic()` function is responsible for changing pictures and it works fine but I still cannot acquire fade effect. Do you have any idea what would be wrong in this code?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function changePic(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
            const urls = [
            "https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg",
            "https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-2.jpg",
            "https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-3.jpg"
            ];

            var picture = document.getElementById("pic");
            if(n>urls.length){slideIndex = 1}
            if(n<1){slideIndex = urls.length}
            picture.src = urls[slideIndex-1];

        }
```

```css
.fade {
       -webkit-animation-name: fade;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
       animation-name: fade;
       animation-duration: 1.5s;
       }

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">  
            <div class="fade">
                    <img id="pic">
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="changePic(-1)">Previous</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="changePic(1)">Next</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Your fade class is applied on the parent `<div>`. the showSlides(n) function is changing the image source of the `<img>`, so the fade effect doesn't show up. Can you put your code in a working fiddle, it'll be easier to help with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add animation on image (I have added class on image named 'fadeImage'). And then on click just remove and add same class again.
Also, don't forget to [trigger a reflow](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/#article-header-id-0) using the offsetWidth before adding class back.

```
picture.classList.remove("fadeImage");
void picture.offsetWidth;
picture.classList.add("fadeImage");
```

See the Snippet below:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
        showSlides(slideIndex);

        function changePic(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex += n);
        }

        function currentSlide(n) {
          showSlides(slideIndex = n);
        }

        function showSlides(n) {
            const urls = [
            "https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-1.jpg",
            "https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-2.jpg",
            "https://www.dike.lib.ia.us/images/sample-3.jpg"
            ];

            var picture = document.getElementById("pic");
            if(n>urls.length){slideIndex = 1}
            if(n<1){slideIndex = urls.length}
            picture.src = urls[slideIndex-1];
            picture.classList.remove("fadeImage");
            void picture.offsetWidth;
            picture.classList.add("fadeImage");

        }
```

```css
.fadeImage {
       -webkit-animation-name: fade;
       -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
       animation-name: fade;
       animation-duration: 1.5s;
       }

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
  @keyframes fade {
    from {opacity: .4}
    to {opacity: 1}
  }
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">  
            <div class="fade">
                    <img id="pic" class="fadeImage">
            </div>

            <a class="prev" onclick="changePic(-1)">Previous</a>
            <a class="next" onclick="changePic(1)">Next</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped. I would never think that there is need to make some kind of "animation restart" in such a scenario.